# C# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject Custom date parse with GMT+1 OR BST

Tags: c#

We are working with the any API in which we are received date time in below format which is not specified.

- 03/21/2018 11:08AM GMT
- 03/26/2018 03:10PM BST
- 03/21/2018 11:08AM GMT+1

How to convert this date time while parsing JSON.

We have try with this json IsoDateTimeConverter

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateFormatConverter(string format) => DateTimeFormat = format;
}
```

And use in property

```
 [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt Z")]
        public DateTime createdOn { get; set; }
```

Received the error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `DateFormatString` as `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt \"GMT\"z"` where
`z` specified the offset value. Since Timezone abbreviation are not recognized so you can not put a format which works on various timezone that's why `GMT` is mentioned the specified the format.

**Why abbreviation are not recognized**

Abbreviations have a many-to-one association. For instance "AMT" means different things, depending on your culture, what part of the world you are in and the context of your application.

```
AMT "Armenia Time" Asia          UTC + 4 hours 
AMT "Amazon Time"  South America UTC - 4 hours
```

**Full Solution Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class TestClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id : {0} Date : {1}", this.Id, this.Date);
    }
}
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = "[{\"id\":1, \"date\":\"03/21/2018 11:08AM GMT\"}, {\"id\":2, \"date\":\"03/18/2018 11:08AM GMT+1\"}, {\"id\":3, \"date\":\"03/15/2018 11:08AM GMT+10\"}]";

        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestClass>>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatString  = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt \"GMT\"z"});
        
        list.ForEach((item) => Console.WriteLine(item));
    }
}
```

This output of above program is below (based on my current culture which is en-US)

> Id : 1 Date : 3/21/2018 11:08:00 AM
>
> Id : 2 Date : 3/18/2018 10:08:00 AM
>
> Id : 3 Date : 3/15/2018 1:08:00 AM

Check the live fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pqWtgU).

Comment: Appreciated for your replay but the issue was we don't have fix GMT it might be have the BST or CEST and then it will create the issues also this all are comes in single json response other wise i will do it dynamic based on the country. For the time being i have replace using string regex but it's not good solution.

Comment: Yes, replacing is a temp solution but it's not foolproof as mentioned in my answer. I would suggest if the source of Json can be changed to have  Time either in UTC format or with one specific Timezone format.